# sed: adding space around colon

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I was trying to write a sed command where if it finds a colon without surrounding spaces, it will put one space before and after the colon, that is, `abc:def` will be converted to `abc : def`. I am doing like this:

```
echo "abc:def" | sed -e 's/[^\s]\+:[^\s]\+/ : /g'
```

the output is still `abc:def`, how do I do it? what is wrong with my above command?

Answer (score 1):

`\s` to mean space in `sed` is not portable - for example in POSIX  implementations your expression will not match e.g. (GNU sed, in posix mode):

```
$ echo "abc:def" | sed --posix -e 's/[^\s]\+:[^\s]\+/ : /g'
abc:def
```

However if your expression *did* match, it would not do what you want since it will replace the entire sequence e.g. (GNU sed, in non-posix mode):

```
$ echo "abc:def" | sed -e 's/[^\s]\+:[^\s]\+/ : /g'
 :
```

Probably what you want is something more like `s/\([^[:blank:]]\):\([^[:blank:]]\)/\1 : \2/` e.g.

```
$ echo "abc:def" | sed -e 's/\([^[:blank:]]\):\([^[:blank:]]\)/\1 : \2/g'
abc : def
```

[As far as I can see the repetition operator `\+` - which is also not portable - is unnecessary.]

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
echo "abc:def" | sed 's@\([^\s]\):\([^\s]\)@\1 : \2@g'
```

I've tested this with GNU sed, not sure about BSD sed.

You need capture groups if you want to preserve parts of the original match, which is what the `\(...\)` and `\1` and `\2` are doing. Also, you don't need the `+` qualifier since all you care about is the immediate neighbors.

Comment: `sed` on OpenBSD seems to work with your expression.